# Get entire row distances from numpy condensed distance matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy condensed distance matrix generated from a set of data points, x:

```
dists = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(x)
```

For the distance between data points i and j (assuming i < j), I understand that I can retrieve the index from the condensed matrix via:

```
condensed_inx = lambda i,j,n: i*n + j - i*(i+1)/2 - i - 1  # n is the number of data points
```

Then, I can get the distance between points i and j via:

```
dists[condensed_inx(i, j, n)]
```

For a single distance, this is trivial. However, I can't figure out a fast/efficient way to grab all of the distances for all distances that involve data point i.  This is what I currently have:

```
n = n = scipy.spatial.distance.num_obs_y(dists) #Get number of data points from condensed matrix
for i in range(n):
    #Get all distance indices relative to data point i
    inx = []
    for j in range(n):
        if i < j:
            inx.append(condensed_inx(i, j, n))
        elif i > j:
            inx.append(condensed_inx(j, i, n))
        else:
            continue
    #Get distances relative to data point i
    distance_for_i = dists[np.array(inx, dtype=np.uint64)]

    #Do some calculations with the distances_for_i
    #For example
    print np.mean(distance_for_i)
```

**Update:** It looks like the inefficiency comes from the "condensed_inx" lambda function.

Comment: yes, the lambda will destroy your efficiency, and no, there is no 'fast' way of extracting all the distances from a single point. even if you come up with a vectorized expression for generating the coordinates, you cannot avoid a lot of random memory accesses. If the performance of doing this query is a major concern, then having the non-condensed matrix at your disposal is much preferred, if you can spare the doubled memory.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are dealing with very large arrays, you're probably better off constructing the square distance matrix using [`squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) and then doing things with each of the rows. For instance, your mean example becomes

```
dists = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(x)
square = scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(dists)
print square.mean(axis=1)
```